# Perform Regex on value returned by Regex

Tags: regex

This is probably straightforward but I'm not even sure which phrase I should google to find the answer.  Forgive my noobiness.

I've got strings (filenames) that look like this:

```
site12345678_date20160912_23001_to_23100_of_25871.txt
```

What this naming convention means is "Records 23001 through 23100 out of 25871 for site 12345678 for September 12th 2016 (20160912)"

What I want to do is extract the date part (those digits between `_date` and the following `_`)

The Regex:  `.*(_date[0-9]{8}).*` will return the string `_date20160912`.  But what I'm actually looking for is just `20160912`.  Obviously, `[0-8]{8}` doesn't give me what I want in this case because that could be confused with the site, or potentially record counts

How can I responsibly accomplish this sort of 'substringing' with a single regular expression?

Comment: Just use capturing groups: `/_date([0-9]{8})/` to extract the numeric part. Or lookbehinds (`/(?<=_date)[0-9]{8}/`) [[demo](https://regex101.com/r/wU1iU7/1)] if your target platform has this feature. Hint: JS hasn't.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: You just need to readjust the parentheses - `.*_date([0-9]{8}).*`

Comment: Use what you've got, no need to be fancy. There is no rationale to say I only want to match a substring. I doesn't matter if you use assertions or not, the same text is being found and with assertions it's up to 2 times slower. Regex partitions substrings for you when you use capture groups, just put it around what you want/know will be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to shift you parentheses so as to change the capture group from including '_date' in it. Then you would want to look for your capture group #1:

If done in python, for example, it would look something like:

```
import re
regex = '.*_date([0-9]{8}).*'
str = 'site12345678_date20160912_23001_to_23100_of_25871.txt'
m = re.match(regex, str)
print m.group(0)   # the whole string
print m.group(1)   # the string you are looking for '20160912'
```

See it in action here: https://eval.in/641446

Comment: Oh geez. I should have tried that in the first place.  Works like a charm in Pentaho Spoon. Thanks!   :)

Answer (score 0):

> The Regex:  `.*(_date[0-9]{8}).*` will return the string `_date20160912`.

That means you are using the regex in a method that requires a full string match, and you can access Group 1 value. The only thing you need to change in the regex is the capturing group placement:

```
.*_date([0-9]{8}).*
       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oY5iQ0/1).